# Filling image source urls in client side javascript templates using ajax requests

Tags: javascript, http, jquery, dust.js, client-side-templating

I am trying to use client side templating library dust.js. I want to fill the "src" attribute of "img" tag ({profile.picUrl} in the code) using a value retrieved from the server using Ajax(in Json format).

The problem is that before the Ajax call is made, the browser tries to load the image resulting in a HTTP 404 response ("src" contains a template placeholder) . Is there a way to do this without a 404 request to the server?

Here is a sample which replicates the problem:

```
<body>
    <div class="template">
    hi {profile.user}
    <img src="{profile.picUrl}" />
    <div id="actions">
        {#actions}
        <a href="{url}">{text}</a><br /><br />
        {/actions}
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
       function fillTemplates(responsedat, status, xhr) {
            if (status === "success") {
                template = $('.template').html();
                dust.compileFn(template,"t");
                dust.render("t", responsedat, function (err,out) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        $('.template').html(out);
                    }

                });
                $('.template').show();
            }
        }
        $.get('landing.jsp', {}, fillTemplates);
        $.ready(function () {
            $('.template').hide();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

PS: Names in the braces({profile.user}) are used to fill values in the templates in dust.js syntax

Answer (score 1):

Generally when I see client-side templates being used, the template itself is not a part of the "active" DOM.  It is often in a script block, e.g. example from backbone: http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/01/backbone-js-lessons-learned-and-improved-sample-app/

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Rj2Hd/1/

```
<html>

<body>
    <script type="text/template" id="template">
    hi {profile.user}
    <img src="{profile.picUrl}" />
    <div id="actions">
        {#actions}
        <a href="{url}">{text}</a><br /><br />
        {/actions}
    </div>
    </script>
    <script>
       function fillTemplates(responsedat, status, xhr) {
            if (status === "success") {
                template = $('#template').html();

alert(template);
        // your stuff here
            }
        }


        $(function () {
            fillTemplates(null, 'success', null);
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the placeholder value for source, it should be as simple as giving it a real address or not providing one until you hear back from the AJAX.